# Call a method in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, method-call

I want to write clear button method in one class in another package. 
And i want to call that method in clear button as button click event.

Eg-

Package A class a <---- I want to write method in here.

Package B class b <---- in here i have that clear button i want to call that method here.

I'm facing some error in text fields!!!.

```
public boolean Clear(){
    boolean clearDate =false;
    Connection dbConn = null;

    StaffId_Text.setText("");
    First_Name_Text.setText("");
    Middle_Name_Text.setText("");
    Last_Name_Text.setText("");
    Civil_Status_Text.setText("");
    NIC_Text.setText("");
    Email_Text.setText("");
    Address_Text.setText("");
    Contact_Number_Text.setText("");

    return clearDate;
}
```

Comment: I don't thin it has anything to do with Netbeans.

Comment: You can't access variables that are not declared in the method, class or passed as a method argument. So you could think about passing a list of `JTextField`s (I guess you use that type) and call `setText("")` for every entry. Like `public boolean Clear(List<JTextField> textFields)` and inside the method: (pseudo code) `for each JTextField as entry in textFields { entry.setText(""); }`.

Comment: I didn't get your annwer

Comment: problem is that text fields are in one package. the method is in one package. That text fields are have to clear.the problem is when i type the text fields name in that class there are errors showing

Comment: In order to use a variable inside a method this variable has to be "known" there. This can be done either be declare a variable like `private String text` or by passing the variable to method as an argument like `b.Clear(textField)`. That way the method `Clear` knows the variable `textField` and can work with it. Now you can pass every single text field to that method or you can use a collection of text fields to do that. Both ways can work.

Comment: can you show the sample code that i want to type

Comment: Just a few questions for clarification: Is this for homework or is this for a personal project? If for homework, usually there will be stipulations and rules regarding what can and cannot be done code-wise. Have you gone through a basic Java textbook or the main sections of an intro to Java tutorial yet, to enable you to understand fully what are classes, methods, variables, the differences between static and instance fields and methods? This is important as it will allow us to know what you need help in and what you already know.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a variable inside a method this variable has to be "known" there. This can be done either be declare a variable like `private String text` or by passing the variable to method as an argument like `b.Clear(textField)`. That way the method `Clear` knows the variable `textField` and can work with it.

This is an example how this can be done:

```
public boolean clear(JTextField... textfields) { // method names should begin
    boolean clearDate = false;                   // with a lower case letter
    Connection dbConn = null;

    for (JTextField textField : textfields) {
        textField.setText("");
    }

    return clearDate;
}
```

Here I declare a method called `clear` which will take an amount of variables of type `JTextField`. Inside that method I iterate over every passed JTextField and call the method `setText("")` on it.

Now you can call your method like this:

```
public void clearEvent() {
    b.clear(staffIdText, firstNameText, middleNameText, [and so on...]);
}
```

You can pass as many JTextFields to this method as you like.

You can also use a list like I mentioned in the comment, but I guess this variant here is much more convenient.

Comment: What is that b??
where can i declare that?

Comment: `b` is the name of your second class in your second package of your example. You can name it like you want. But I guess you already have an instance of class "b" in your first class. So just use it :).